# OS basic graphic driver

Tags: operating-system, gpu

I was told that GPU vendors make actual DirectX/OpenGL API implementation in their driver. However,
Windows use DirectX to draw itself (OpenGL in Linux case), but OS can draw itself even when GPU driver
is not installed. So, does Windows contain some base DirectX implementation that works on all GPUs?

Comment: If you try to run a game with the fallback video drivers, it will either not work at all or be *very* slow. Often, you'll already see a performance difference on the desktop, meaning that without the proper driver you'll see how windows get refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

No. Without GPU drivers, windows will use an API standard called VESA that all modern GPUs implement that allow standard non-accelerated drawing.